# Issue with date timestamp to Oracle SQL Loader. Error is missing comma

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

Here's what I have in my control card.

```
updt_tmstmp "YYYY-MON-DD HH24.MI.SS",
```

But when I load the error code is

> ORA-00917: missing comma

Not sure how to fix.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It would probably help if you posted a little bit more of the control file; anyway, it seems that `TO_DATE` is missing, e.g.

```
updt_tmstmp "to_date(:updt_tmstmp, 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24.MI.SS')",
```